# "unresolved dependency" for Spark 2.0.1 on SBT

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, dependencies, sbt

With my build.sbt

```
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.1"
```

I try to get Spark into my sbt 0.13 project, but IntelliJ 2016.2.5 gives the error "unresolved dependency". What am I doing wrongly?

There is no proxy and it works with if I say "2.0.0" instead of "2.0.1", but that is not so nice...

Also: it seems to work in the CLI, but not in IntelliJ.

Comment: add resolver. check answer for more info

Comment: Do you have a proxy in the way? Are you able to resolve other versions of spark? Are you able to resolve other versions of any other dependencies?

Comment: @JustinPihony: no proxy. Yes, it works with 2.0.0.

Comment: Maybe clear out your intellij directory and try again? Otherwise you might be better to open an issue with intellij themselves

Comment: @JustinPihony: What do you mean with "clear out your intellij directory"?

Comment: @Make42 you could try to rebuild the project in intellij as sometimes it caches some stuff `Build` -> `Rebuild project`. Also, you could try to re-import the project again `File` -> `New` -> `Project from existing sources..` (be sure to tick `Use auto-import` then).

Comment: @cyrillk: I rebuild it a lot of times. I also tried to rebuild it from existing sources. Same result.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box SBT loads only https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ repository which as far as I can tell currently has no Apache Spark. Maybe another project you builded fetched it from other repo and now it is resolved using you local Ivy cache?

You can solve the issue by adding another maven reporotory to your project like:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver sonatypeRepo "public",
  Resolver typesafeRepo "releases",
)
```

UPDATE: If you want to use MavenRepository (you are **not** using it out of the box) you can try adding:

```
resolvers += "MavenRepository" at "https://mvnrepository.com/"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response :-), unfortuantely your solution does not work. Also I am pretty sure I did not build anything with Spark with SBT. So far I only played around with Jupyter and apache toree kernel. By the way: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11 looks like there is Apache Spark - even in 2.0.1.

Comment: Yes there is, but by default Ivy uses this one: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml . So you need to add some repository that has it.

Comment: A note but for Scala libraries you can write it like `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.1"` - `%%` spare you the need to write scala version at the end ;)

Comment: Which one does have it? The ones you provided seem not to. At least I still get "unresolved dependency".

Comment: I updated the answer, try adding the one you checked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127261/discussion-between-mateusz-kubuszok-and-make42).

Answer (score 0):

i am currently using this build.sbt to get spark2 depdendencies but it seems i am not getting any as code fails with exception ss uch as

C:\Users\marco\SparkExamples\src\main\scala\MachineLearningExamples.scala:3: object mllib is not a member of package org.apache.spark
[error] import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
[error]                         ^
[error] C:\Users\marco\SparkExamples\src\main\scala\MachineLearningExamples.scala:4: object classification is not a member of package org.apache.spark.ml
[error] import org.apache.spark.ml.classification._
[error]                            ^

here's my build.sbt.... wondering if anyone can try it to exclude sbt issues on my local machine. thanks

```
    name := "SparkExamples"
    version := "1.0"
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
    val sparkVersion = "2.0.1"


    libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.8" % "test"
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.5",
                        "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.5",
                        "org.clapper" %% "grizzled-slf4j" % "1.0.2")
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark"%%"spark-core"   % sparkVersion 
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark"%%"spark-streaming"   % sparkVersion 
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark"%%"spark-mllib"   % sparkVersion 
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark"%%"spark-streaming-flume-sink" % sparkVersion     
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark"%%"spark-sql"   % sparkVersion 


    resolvers += "MavenRepository" at "https://mvnrepository.com/"
```

If i use sparkVersion 1.6.0 (with a minor tweak to the spark-streaming-flume dependency) everything works fie

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [Mateusz Kubuszok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305121/mateusz-kubuszok) is close. I simply add http://central.maven.org/maven2 to my resolvers, rather than https://mvnrepository.com/.

```
resolvers  += "MavenRepository" at "http://central.maven.org/maven2"
```

This seems to have many of the spark dependencies.